# PowerShell send-mailmessage deprecated - future consequences for people still relying on it?

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I would like to understand what is going to happen to PowerShell send-mailmessage, which is a "deprecated" app since 2020 I reckon.

Here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3) it is suggested to use MailKit from now on (https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md and https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).
This is still in development though and not as well documented being quite recent (in this case, I refer to additional resources such as forums and blogs where issues with the app are discussed and solved).
Moreover, I am an IT naive user and a PowerShell novel student, so the learning curve for me would be very steep.
So, I would like to keep on using send-mailmessage.

I am currently still using this app with the power admin module (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/powerapps/get-started-powerapps-admin?view=pa-ps-latest), which allows a secure connection.
And I would like to keep using it in the future (in 2023 and later) as well.
The only issue to my understanding is that send-mailmessage will not be updated following modern protocols for email sending.
However, for now this is not a problem.
I can use it with outlook, zohomail, and gmail, with the most recent developments that requires allowing less secure apps and the usage of an app-specific password.

So, to sum up, am I right or wrong to think that in the future we can still use this app, although not recommended?

I would be using it for trivial messaging, without sensitive information in it.

Many thanks for claryfing!

Comment: This is really not a PS code-specific issue, which is what we are here to assist with. It's one asking for an opinion about the future of X or Y thing. All are feeling this pain, but we are in no position to say what will and will not be supported by MS or other 3rdP kits, unless we specifically work for those orgs or support those kits and are an authoritative voice of said same.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this here, since it is too long for general comment.

This question has been asked a few times around the web. See the guidance that has been stated thus far, as a reference to what you've already uncovered.

Notes I've shared with the orgs I have and support.

***As per MS and the move to drop Basic Auth for Modern Auth***. You and your organizations/customers really need to stop using Send-MailMessage. Details here:

```
Send-O365EWSMailMessage
```

> https://github.com/ArchitektApx/Send-O365EWSMailMessage
>
> Send-O365EWSMailMessage
>
> Replacement for the Send-MailMessage Cmdlet in Powershell
>
> Since Send-MailMessage is considered to be obsolete, this function
> provides a (pretty much) "drop-in" replacement using the Microsoft
> Exchange Web Services Managed API.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage
>
> Warning
>
> The Send-MailMessage cmdlet is obsolete. ***This cmdlet does not***
> ***guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers.*** While there is no
> immediate replacement available in PowerShell, we recommend you do not
> use Send-MailMessage. For more information, see Platform Compatibility
> note DE0005.
>
> Send-MgUserMail
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users.actions/send-mgusermail?view=graph-powershell-1.0
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951
>
> https://www.powershellcenter.com/2022/09/07/powershell-script-to-simplify-send-mgusermail/
>
> Moving on from Send-MailMessage: Sending Email from PowerShell using
> the Graph AP
>
> https://practical365.com/upgrade-powershell-scripts-sendmailmessage/